# What was title of circa 1950s sci fi movie where a flying saucer is accidentally opened by electric razor?

Tags: story-identification, flying-saucer

I remember watching a sci fi movie as a child but haven't been able to identify the title.  If I recall, a flying saucer was found in China (?) but they couldn't find out how to enter it.  Then one of the people is shaving with and electric razor and the sound of the razor causes an entrance to the saucer appear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*[The Bamboo Saucer](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0062704/)*

[image: Movie Poster]

> A flying saucer hidden in a Red Chinese peasant village is sought by teams from the United States and U.S.S.R. On finding it, they band together to explore the saucer and take a trip into space.

[This Google Answer](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/772844.html) notes the razor connection:

> I believe your movie is a 1968 film called "The Bamboo Saucer," also
>   known as "Collision Course." The plot involves a flying saucer found
>   in Red China inside an old church (which also was used as a barnyard
>   for farm animals). Scientists discover by accident that the buzzing
>   sound of an electric razor will cause a door to open.

A trailer:

Comment: I concur with this answer.

Comment: Wow, that was easy, take that Best Buy!  Thanks for rapid response.